# Carrierwave get image by url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, image-upload

I need to get some images by the url.

The urls are like http://img.wallsbay.com/large/2014/05/2665.jpg but 2014 and 2665 are changings.

My controller has this params:

```
  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:content, :remote_content_url, :id)
  end
```

And i tried to get image from the url like this:

```
@image.remote_content_url = 'http://img.wallsbay.com/large/#{:content}/05/#{:id}jpg'
```

but remote_content_url is undefined method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this issue by adding `attr_accessor :remote_content_url` into my image model.

Answer (score 3):

The `remote_<attr_name>_url` attribute is to upload images by a given URL.

```
@model.remote_content_url = "http://img.wallsbay.com/large/2014/05/2665.jpg"
@model.save
@model.content_url // => "<upload-dir>/2665.jpg"
```

Use `@model.content_url` to retrieve the url to the uploaded image.

To apply a transformation use `@model.content_url(:square)`.

Comment: I want to upload more than one image but i can't use remote_<attr_name>_url .

Comment: Carrierwave does not handle multi upload like this. Youll need to create a record for each image. I'd consider using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to acheive this.

Comment: I don't need dropzone.js right now. I need to use remote_content_url but is undefined.

Comment: Can you provide the full context or example of all the code?

Comment: This is the code basically but i want to know why i can't use remote_content_url. Where should i define it? I see in rails 3 you should use attr_accsesible for remote_content_url but i don't know how can i do this in rails 4.2.6.

Comment: Its only for uploading an image from a remote source. Ideally in an create/update action before the save call.

Comment: Did you mount the uploader to content in your model? It's hard to help further without more context of all the code.

Comment: Yeah i mount it in the image class like this: mount_uploaders :content, ImageUploader

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the image URL would be `@image.content.url` assuming `content` is the attribute you are using for Carrierwave.

Comment: Yeah i know but i want something like that: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-remote-image-urls-to-your-seedfile